# flutter run failed and getting location related issues

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Flutter 2.2.3 •

channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

Framework • revision f4abaa0735 (4 months ago) • 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700

Engine • revision 241c87ad80
Tools • Dart 2.13.4

- /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-2.1.0/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:29:
  error: cannot find symbol if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=
  Build.VERSION_CODES.S) { ^ symbol: variable S location: class
  VERSION_CODES
  /Users/sonusaini/Documents/application/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-2.1.0/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:30:
  error: cannot find symbol position.put("is_mocked",
  location.isMock()); ^ symbol: method isMock() location: variable
  location of type Location 2 errors FAILURE: Build failed with an
  exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task
  ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation
  failed; see the compiler error output for details. * Try: Run with
  --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in
  21s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

---

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't** intend to suport Android 12, just set your geolocator to 7.6.2

pubspec.yaml

```
  geolocator: 7.6.2
```

Have a look into this issue: [#866](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/866)

---

If you **do** intend to support Andorid 12:

First update compile SDK version to 31 and you must update your JDK version to 11

android\app\build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 31
```

more details here: [#868](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/868#issuecomment-944069785)

it may work but you will receive a lot of mappings warnings, to solve it you have to update your Gradle version, to do it I use Android Studio:

Open you flutter project on Android Studio, then
Tools > Flutter > Open Android Module in Android Studio then select new window.
it will sync Gradle and will ask if you want to update it!

Answer (score 0):

If u are not targeting Android 12 add this to pubspec.yaml

```
geolocator: 7.6.2
```

**Note**: please do not use the caret **^** symbol